# Best way of working with ListView

Tags: ios, swift

Hey guys I´m in the process of learning swift right now and I try to program a Game. I want to show a list with items and different attributes to these Items.
So first I have User choice of where they can select either Food or Toys or other stuff coming in the future. Here I tried to only do one ViewController and change the stuff inside depending on the choice. Right now I have these Items in an Array from a Class. 
They look like this:

```
    class FoodData {
    var name: String
    var description = "Basic Food"
    var owned = 0
    var taste = 0
    var price = 0
    var water = 0
    var image = "default.png"
    init(name: String){
    self.name=name
    }
}
class ToyData {
    var name: String
    var description = "Basic Item"
    var owned = 0
    var price = 0
    var joy = 0
    var image = "default.png"
    init(name: String){
    self.name=name
    }
}
```

I initialise these with:

```
    var foodLoad=[FoodData]() 

    func loadFoodData(){
    foodLoad.append(FoodData(name: "IceCream"))
    foodLoad[0].description="Very Cold"
    foodLoad[0].owned=10
}
```

Same style for the Toys. Now I have these two Classes in two Arrays called foodLoad[i] and toyLoad[I]

For the Table View I fill it with the protocols

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let shopCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: shopCellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! ShopCellStyle

    shopCell.shopNameLabel?.text = shopData[indexPath.row].name
    shopCell.shopImageView?.image = UIImage(named: shopData[indexPath.row].image)
    shopCell.shopPriceLabel?.text = String(shopData[indexPath.row].price) + currency
    return shopCell
```

So my Idea was to assign shopData with the User choice.
But if I assign shopData = foodLoad, I can't change that to toyLoad anymore. So maybe you can give me a hint of how to solve this the best way.

Comment: Don't use only one VC. After the user chooses, present a different VC depending on what the user has chosen. One VC for toys, one for food etc.

Comment: With VC you mean ViewController? I tried to do it in 1 because the Data is pretty much the same just from different classes. So it would be the exact same ViewController just with toyLoad instead of foodLoad. I hoped that there would be an easy way to save the ViewController but I guess not. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, of course.

Answer (score 0):

for your cellForRowAt indexPath:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let shopCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "shopCellIdentifier", for: indexPath) as! ItemCell

    if selection == "food" {
        shopCell.shopNameLabel?.text = foodLoad[indexPath.row].name
        shopCell.shopImageView?.image = UIImage(named: 
        foodLoad[indexPath.row].image)
        shopCell.shopPriceLabel?.text = String(foodLoad[indexPath.row].price) + currency
    } 
    else if selection == "toys" {
        shopCell.shopNameLabel?.text = toyLoad[indexPath.row].name
        shopCell.shopImageView?.image = UIImage(named: 
        toyLoad[indexPath.row].image)
        shopCell.shopPriceLabel?.text = String(toyLoad[indexPath.row].price) + currency
   }
   return shopCell
}
```

You'd also want the numberOfRowsInSection UITableView function. Call tableview.reloadData() when the user changes the type selection.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but its not quite what I was looking for. I wanted to just have one of them active so the TableView doesn't get too crowded.

Comment: This might not be too elegant, but you could keep the user's choice as a variable. In all relevant TableView functions, you could check the user's choice before supplying the tableview with data. I'll edit my answer